# MySQL SET NAMES Query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Everytime when I connect to MySQL I run the following query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Can I safely remove this query when I set it in the MySQL Conf (my.conf)?

I found this with google: http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/mysql-forcing-utf-8-compliance-for-all-connections/

Is this enough or am I missing something? Or is there a better method?

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a better method?

yes.

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

is the **only** reliable method.